# C pass pointer as argument in function

Tags: c, function, pointers, parameters

I came across the following code:

```
int H3I_hook(int (*progress_fn)(int*), int *id)
{
...
}
```

I don't understand the purpose of `(int*)` at the end of the first argument?

Comment: Do you understand it is a pointer to a function?

Comment: @usr: Not even close.

Comment: @usr: If OP understood function pointers, we wouldn't be here.

Comment: There is a cool little program in K&R C book, around pg 137 [here](http://www.ime.usp.br/~pf/Kernighan-Ritchie/C-Programming-Ebook.pdf) that parses complicated pointer declarations to english descriptions and back.  Definitely worth a read

Comment: *I don't understand the purpose of `(int*)` at the end of the first argument* : There is a difference between "argument" and "parameter".  What you are referring as argument is actually a parameter.

Comment: @jenesaisquoi: There's also an online version (no idea if it's based off of the K&R one or not, but it accomplishes the same thing): http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/

Comment: As others have mentioned you can use the program `cdecl` if you have it, or just use the website [to parse complicated C declarations and more.](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int+%28*progress_fn%29%28int*%29)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Demystifying:

```
int (*progress_fn)(int*)
```

it can be interpreted like below:

```
int (*progress_fn)(int*)
 ^       ^          ^
 |       |          |___________ pointer to integer as argument
 |       |
 |     pointer to any function that has V and takes ^
 |
 |__________________________return type an integer
```

Answer (score 2):

`int (*progress_fn)(int*)` is **function pointer** decleration, and `(int *)` is the list of parameters the function accepts.

So, this:

```
int (*progress_fn)(int*)
```

is a pointer to a function that will return an `int` and will receive one parameter, of type `int*`.

So you have to understand that `progess_fn` is the *actual parameter*. All its relevant components define how the function's prototype is actually.

---

For more, read [How do function pointers in C work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work)

Comment: Maybe you should point out that `progress_fn` is the actual parameter, and the rest is how you specify what its type is.

Comment: @ScottHunter something like the edit I just made?

Comment: @gsamaras, The part under the bar is rather redundant.

Answer (score 2):

Given this declarartion:

```
int progress_callback(int* a);
//                    ^ this is the (int*) you asked about
```

You can call `H3I_hook` like this:

```
int id = something;
int x = H3I_hook(progress_callback, &id);
```

Comment: The question does not appear to be about `typedef`s.

Comment: @ScottHunter I've changed that, but the answer used `typedef` to avoid the confusion between an int pointer and a function pointer.